# Does cakephp have an upload scaffolding option out of the box?

Tags: php, cakephp

using the automatic $scaffold is working great for me, but it'd be even better if for binary columns it'd create a fileupload input. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not "out of the box".

You'll need to customize your view to add file input/upload fields to your form.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html#customizing-scaffold-views

Be sure to create your form correctly:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create

You can also use a few popular ways to handle file uploads. Of course, it's only a couple of lines of code if you wish to just upload a file, but if you need more power you'd be better off using one of the existing solutions.

https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload   * My top choice. Many features. Well written.

https://github.com/davidpersson/media

https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack

https://github.com/milesj/cake-uploader